# Unable to set data for the next variable after I set the data for another variable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want to fetch data from firebase and display it on a form so a user can update the information they input previously, but I am only able to display the data for "schoolName" and the whole data I fetch from firebase is gone. I did a console.log(data) to check it but it doesn't display anything. Which part of my codes do I need to change to be able to display the data for "schoolName" and "studentName"?

```
<html>
 <tbody>
  <tr id='schoolName' *ngFor="let field of Form.value.schoolName; 
  let i = index">
  <td class="text-center">
  {{i}}
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" name='schoolName' placeholder='Name' class="form- 
  control"
  [(ngModel)]="field.schoolName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
  </td>
  <td class="text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"                                          
  (click)="delete_school_row(field.id)">Delete</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='studentName' *ngFor="let field of Form.value.studentName; 
  let i = index">
  <td class="text-center">
  {{i}}
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" name='studentName' placeholder='Name' class="form- 
  control"
  [(ngModel)]="field.studentName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
  </td>
  <td class="text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"                                          
  (click)="delete_student_row(field.id)">Delete</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</html>

<ts>
if (this.mode == "edit") {
  this.schoolService.GetDataById(this.id).subscribe(data => 
{
this.Form.value.schoolName = [];
    if (data.schoolName) {
      for (var b = 0; b < data.schoolName.length; b++) {
        this.Form.value.schoolName= data.schoolName[b]
      }
    }
    this.Form.controls["schoolName"].setValue(data.schoolName)
console.log(data.studentName)
this.Form.value.studentName = [];
    if (data.studentName) {
      for (var b = 0; b < data.studentName.length; b++) {
        this.Form.value.studentName= data.studentName[b]
      }
    }
    this.Form.controls["studentName"].setValue(data.studentName)
});
}
</ts>
```

Comment: Can you please add your .ts file code where you are fetching from Firebase?

Comment: @CodeChanger added!

Answer (score 0):

You have to push item in array 
use

`this.Form.value.schoolName.push(data.schoolName[b])`
instead of using `this.Form.value.schoolName= data.schoolName[b]`

and I don't know exactly why you would push item into `this.Form.value.schoolName`, 
you can push items to global initiated value in your ts file since you're not using form in your HTML, you will still be able to bind it to any control via `[(ngModel)]`

Also I believe using `forEach` instead of `for` loop in this case will be more convenient.

*Recap:

```
let schoolNames = [], studentNames = [];
if (this.mode == "edit") {
  this.schoolService.GetDataById(this.id).subscribe(data => 
{
this.Form.value.schoolName = [];
    if (data.schoolName)            
           forEach(data.studentName, (key, value) => {
           schoolNames.push(value);
        });
    //this.Form.controls["schoolName"].setValue(data.schoolName)
console.log(data.studentName)
this.Form.value.studentName = [];
    if (data.studentName)
           forEach(data.studentName, (key, value) => {
           schoolNames.push(value);
        });
    //this.Form.controls["studentName"].setValue(data.studentName)
});
}
```

and set your HTML loops `*ngFor="let field of schoolNames`

I don't know if that helps or not, but if not please try to clarify your question because it's the best I can offer with provided information.